# Localhost Error - This page can't be found - Asp.net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

I am trying to convert HTML content into a pdf file. When I click the the Print Receipt Button, it should show the pdf file of the receipt. On the contrary, it gives **This page can't be found** error.

Here is the code for the button:

```
 <form method="post" asp-action="ReceiptAsync">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg p-2" id="generatePdf">Print Receipt</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Here is the code for the controller method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ReceiptAsync()
        {
            using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                var viewResult = _compositeViewEngine.FindView(ControllerContext, "ViewReceipt", false);
                if (viewResult == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("View Can't Be Found");
                }
                var viewDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary());
                var viewContext = new ViewContext(

                    ControllerContext,
                    viewResult.View,
                    viewDictionary,
                    TempData,
                    stringWriter,
                    new HtmlHelperOptions()
                    );
                await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);

                var htmlToPdf = new HtmlToPdf(1000, 1414);
                htmlToPdf.Options.DrawBackground = true;

                var pdf = htmlToPdf.ConvertHtmlString(stringWriter.ToString());
                var pdfbytes = pdf.Save();

                return File(pdfbytes, "application/pdf");
            }
        }
```

Here is the error screenshot : [image]

Comment: What's your `ReceiptAsync` binding `HttpMethod`

Comment: Hi @Azhar Qureshi,  any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer? If not, could you please follow up to let me know? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Rena sorry for not updating till yet. I am not able to access my system as I am sick since last 3 days. Today in the evening time I will most probably try out your solution and give an update. Thanks a lot. 

Comment: Hi @Azhar Qureshi, take care of yourself. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to ASP.NET Core 3.0:

- The preceding action could be accessed at the `Payment/ReceiptAsync`
  route.
- Link generation required specifying the `Async` suffix.

After ASP.NET Core 3.0:

- The preceding action can be accessed at `Payment/Receipt` route.
- Link generation doesn't require specifying the `Async` suffix.

So you need change your code to:

```
<form method="post" asp-action="Receipt">   //change `asp-action` here...
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg p-2" id="generatePdf">Print Receipt</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Reference:

[[Discussion] Async suffix for controller action names will be trimmed by default](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8998)

[Async suffix removal from controller action names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#async-suffix-removal-from-controller-action-names)